# Where, online (preferably free) can learn medical topics in depth, specifically gastroenterology?

Tags: human-biology, health, gastroenterology, learning

**Where, online (preferably free) can learn medical topics in depth, specifically gastroenterology?**

I'll try to be concise and to the point:

- I have an Associate of Science degree where I actually specialized in Biology
- I am asking for online classes, texts, videos, or other resources
- My specific interest is in **gastroenterology**
- My need is to understand the subject in depth I imagine several months of research will be required for me to find the answers I need.
- Free or nearly free / very cheap sources are the only sources that interest me as I'm rather poor.

*This is the end of the concise part The next part is to provide context and is skippable if you understand the question already really.*

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that your health is failing. In short, you can't become an expert just like that, it takes several years of full-time training to become expert. However, there is much publically available information for many topics on the [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) if you search. The latest research is published in journal articles, but these require specialist knowledge to interpret.

Comment: @MattDMo Thank you I am aware that asking for personal medical advice is considered off-topic. I am asking for education advice on the topic of biology. The context section was simply provided to help people understand what context I'm asking from, as to be as complete as I can in my query.

Comment: @bob1 Thank you for the link to the NCBI, I regularly read research (not just research articles) I figure I have about 2-10 to acquire enough knowledge. Simply reading the latest research, while fun, will not help me much as the research when it leads to treatments nearly always leads to treatments for people with significant money or charity cases, and I just don't make a compelling charity case.

**I am seeking to spend the time and effort (not money) that is required to learn the topic of gastroenterology.**

Comment: Check out https://clinicaltrials.gov for information on ongoing and upcoming... you guessed it! Clinical trials! You don't have to be independently wealthy or a charity case to join a trial, you just need to be (relatively) close to a participating hospital. Many patients are often eligible for trials, and don't participate simply through lack of knowledge of their existence, either their own or their doctor's. If you live near a research hospital, they often have many trials ongoing.

Comment: Also, upon rereading your question, I've decided to retract my close vote. I suggest editing out the "context" part at the bottom. We have to be very careful treading around questions like these, because askers can potentially take the first reference off the list of 10 someone provides, skim it and decide that's their answer, then treat themselves accordingly without involving a medical professional or understanding that a single datum of research does not necessarily indicate the way things truly are.

Comment: @MattDMo - I wouldn't do that. There's a lot going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Although I voted to close this question, my advice is too long for a comment.

The short answer is, **you can't**. You can't read enough to learn "gastroenterology". You can go to med school (my oldest classmate was 44), or PA school (much less time). You need to know most of the basics of medicine/biology to understand one organ system, because they are interconnected. Gastroenterologists (off the top of my head) must also understand immunology, endocrinology, neurology, and anatomy (not to mention more basic basics like molecular biology and biochemistry.) Yet, there you are, without an answer. What can you do?

You can pore over the literature, but you won't understand it. You won't know relevant search terms, and whether what you read is reliable. But it doesn't hurt to try. Use Google Scholar instead of Google.

You can write in to various publications (free) where difficult cases are discussed and ask for physicians to help solve the problem or that print difficult cases that were eventually solved to see if they've seen a case like yours or can help you with your problem (The Washington Post and the New York Times are two of the many publications that highlight difficult cases.)

You can "hire" a good patient advocate (not all patient advocates are created equal.) Some people, even physicians, do this work *pro bono*. A good, empathetic physician who does patient advocacy work would be best. They will review all your medical records with a fresh eye, accompany you on your doctor visits, ask the doctor any questions you might not know to ask, and explain to you what your doctor said (patients don't "hear"/retain about 75% of what doctors tell them, and why they are recommending x, y, or z.) They will also give you an opinion (you need to see someone else/this doctor is competent and trustworthy/other).

Sometimes doctors don't know the answers, but since they can't find anything abnormal, they can tell you whatever is going on isn't going to end your life. Sometimes doctors think they know the answers when what they think is incorrect. The problem is that you don't trust your doctors so far, so the only option is to keep seeing specialists until the issue is diagnosed or resolved. It's expensive, and optimally, get an appointment at a medical center especially well known for excellence, and where cases are reviewed by a board comprised of various specialists.

But what you cannot do is "learn gastroenterology".

I know this doesn't answer the question as asked. But **the answer to the question as asked is "nowhere".**

Comment: Thank you so very, very much for your well-written and informative response! I genuinely do appreciate the thought, the effort, and the insight you have shared with me. You have provided me with some new avenues I had not understood existed! I am very tempted to mark this as the answer to my question, and after an additional month of continuing my search, I will!

Comment: I would like to ask, though, who is being helped by "closing" the question? And what can I do to prevent said closing?

Comment: Closing a question is a site-specific cultural thing, and it doesn't really "hurt" anyone. It does help to keep off-topic questions off the site. I only answered because I'm a physician who did *pro bono* patient advocacy work, and because I understand all too well from personal experience what it's like to *know* something isn't right, yet be unable to find a physician who is capable of making the correct diagnosis. In one case, the *ninth* doctor I saw immediately diagnosed me correctly, and I had the needed palliative surgery and medications. ...

Comment: ...I also know how helpless non-medical people can feel in navigating the system. I cared about all my patients, but had a particular soft spot for all patients with difficult diagnoses. That's the reason I provided the answer even though it's off topic.